# parallel training in caret package of R, when using custom sampler

Tags: r, parallel-processing, r-caret

I'm trying to provide my own sampler to the train function of the caret package (because of imbalanced data) and then train the model in a parallel environment. 
If I don't give the sampler to the train it works fine. 
If I give the sampler to the train but not use the parallel capability then again it works fine.
But if I ask it to run in parallel with the sampler, then it gives me an error. I have tried running on two different systems and the result is the same but the error that I get in two situations are different. Here is an example:

```
library(caret)
set.seed(1)
data(iris)

library(DMwR)
library(doParallel)
cl <- makeCluster(3)
cl <- makeCluster(1) #uncommenting this will make the code work 
print(cl)
registerDoParallel(cl)

smote_wrapper <- list(
        name = "custom_smoting",
        func = function(x, y) {
                #print(dim(x))
                print(length(y))
                data <- cbind(x, data.frame(Class = y))
                #print(table(data$Class))
                print("calling smote")
                final <- SMOTE(Class~., data, perc.over = 50, perc.under = 50)
                print("smote over")
                #print(dim(final))
                final$Class <- as.factor(final$Class)
                print(table(final$Class))
                class_index <- which(colnames(final) == "Class")
                print(paste("dim:", dim(final)))
                result <- list(x = final[,-class_index], y = final$Class)
                result
        },
        first = FALSE
)
data(iris)
control <- trainControl(sampling = smote_wrapper)
model <- train(Species~., iris, method = "svmLinear2", trControl = control)
stopCluster(cl)
```

On one system it stops training the mode and gives the error:

```
Error in { : task 1 failed - "object 'out2' not found
```

And on the other system it gives:

```
Something is wrong; all the Accuracy metric values are missing:
Accuracy       Kappa    
 Min.   : NA   Min.   : NA  
 1st Qu.: NA   1st Qu.: NA  
 Median : NA   Median : NA  
 Mean   :NaN   Mean   :NaN  
 3rd Qu.: NA   3rd Qu.: NA  
 Max.   : NA   Max.   : NA  
 NA's   :3     NA's   :3    
Error: Stopping
In addition: Warning message:
In nominalTrainWorkflow(x = x, y = y, wts = weights, info = trainInfo,  :
  There were missing values in resampled performance measures.
```

Maybe sampler doesn't work in parallel?

I was using the latest CRAN installation of caret (6.0.77) but due to another  error ("optimismBoot not found") I had to install the latest version from github (devtools::install_github).

Answer (score 3):

Looks like you might need to export your packages and variables to the cluster

```
registerDoParallel(cl)
# try these lines
clusterEvalQ(cl, { library(DMwR) })
clusterExport(cl, "smote_wrapper")
```

In parallel mode, caret will look in each new worker's environment for packages/variables but if you don't export them, they will not be available. Hope this helps.